# My parents are magicions how to deal with the food that they're preparing?

Tags: halal-haram, food, death, parents, family

My parents are practicing magic to all my family members agree with them except for me and my sister, my father taught others to practice with him and they are making Sihr on me and my sister.
The problem is far big we don't have job, and all their food is haram and we don't have other options.

Should we starve to death or should eat because there is no way to get halal food?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you know your parents income is not halal, but you don't make a living yourself, what do you do, as per Islamic point of view?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62584/if-you-know-your-parents-income-is-not-halal-but-you-dont-make-a-living-yourse)

Answer (score 0):

In Islam/Quran, consuming Haram food is strictly prohibited **except** in cases of necessity or extreme circumstances where there is a risk of starvation. In such situations, where Halal food is not available, it is permissible to consume Haram food to sustain life temporarily.

---

Note that it is crucial to exhaust all possible means to find **lawful** alternatives, such as seeking help from charitable organizations, mosques, or community members!